# Why won't my table shrink below 170px in height?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following code:

```css
#superheader {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#superheader p {
  font-family: Sansation;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#superheader table {
  border: solid;
  height: 100px;
}

#header {
  height: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.5em 0.5em grey;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menuelement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.menuelement:hover {
  background-color: dimgrey;
}

#header>a {
  line-height: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="superheader">
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 630px;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="images/memoji.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Icon"></td>
          <td>
            <p>A TITLE</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="template.html">
    <div class="menuelement">Page1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="index.html">
    <div class="menuelement">Page2</div>
  </a>
  <a href="not_found.html">
    <div class="menuelement">Page3</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The table in this example should be 100px in height, however it won't get smaller than 170px.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your font size and font size line height will exceed the defined space, you can observe this by adding `overflow:hidden` to your table cells and seeing that your font will loose some of its space. Solution: reduce your font size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually you can't control `height` or `width` of the elements with `display: table;` because by default if their cells `height` or `width` is larger than the `height` or `width` of the element with `display: table;` the element will grow. So you need to control the dimension of the cells instead of the table itself.

In your particular case, there are two approaches to overcome this situation.

1. **Controlling the cells:** since you used `p` tag in your table and this tag has a default margin of `1em` on top and bottom you can simply override it and because the inner cells are no longer larger than the table itself you can control its dimensions (As long as they do not smaller than cells). Also, keep in mind the `font-size` and `line-height` will make your cells bigger than usual, but if you want to keep them as it is, you should drop the default margin.

   ```css
   p {
     font-family: Sansation;
     font-size: 50px;
     margin: 0;
   }

   table {
     border: solid;
     height: 100px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><img src="images/memoji.png" alt="Icon"></td>
       <td>
         <p>A TITLE</p>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   ```
2. **Using `display: block;`**: You can simply override the `display` of the table and make it work as `block` but you still need to control the inner elements to do not override the table itself. Also, keep in mind you should control the `width` of the table also because block element by default will fill the available space.

   ```css
   p {
     font-family: Sansation;
     font-size: 50px;
     margin: 0;
   }

   table {
     border: solid;
     height: 100px;
     display: block;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><img src="images/memoji.png" alt="Icon"></td>
       <td>
         <p>A TITLE</p>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `border-spacing: 0px;` to your table style to remove spaces between cells:

```
#superheader table{
    border: solid;
    height: 100px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

and then remove white spaces inside cells:

```
td, td *{
   display: table-cell;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: will it? Do table cells have a default margin value?